# Cannot create an Abstract class when trying to create List<T> from CSV using csv.GetRecords()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, csvhelper

I'm attempting to create a generic method to enable me to parse a CSV document into an object of my choice.

Everything seems to work ok but the results after executing the csv.GetRecords() method are empty and the inner exception of the response is "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created."

I've also tried using the csv.EnumerateRecords(record); and get the same result.

```
    public class ImportManager
    {        
        [Ignore]
        public string FileSeperator { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public string Filename { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<T> ParseFile<T>() where T : class
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Filename))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = this.FileSeperator;
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                var results = csv.GetRecords<T>();
                return results;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyObject : ImportManager
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field2 { get; set; }
        public int Field3 { get; set; }

        public List<MyObject> LoadFile()
        {
            var response = ParseFile<MyObject>();
            return response.ToList<MyObject>();
        }
    }

    MyObject moObjList= new MyObject() { Filename = "MyFileName.txt", FileSeperator = "|" };
    var results = moObjList.LoadFile();
```

Help!

Comment: This is rather peculiar code to start with, you need an instance of `MyObject` just to create a list of `MyObject`? You should really split the methods that load the file and parse them in a class of their own, possibly static methods, but that's a different argument altogether. Secondly, I'm not sure where that error is coming from, do you have some `abstract` classes that you haven't shown here?

Comment: It seems odd to have `MyObject` implement `ImportManager`. Add a generic type parameter to the manager: `public class ImportManager<T>` and remove it from `ParseFile() `. Then `var manager = new ImportManager<MyObject>(); var result = manager.ParseFile().ToList();`. Also, is `MyObject` the real class or just a simplified dummy?

Comment: "I'm attempting to create a generic method to enable me to parse a CSV document into an object of my choice." That's exactly what `.GetRecords<T>` already is.

Comment: Thanks all.  My ImportManager will be doing more than just parsing the file.

Olivier - that still did the same when I tried it that way.

DavidG - No other classes are involved in this operation.  That's what I'm struggling to understand, I'm not trying to create an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding `ToList()` to `csv.GetRecords<T>()` may solve your issue.  `GetRecords<T>()` does a lazy load.  It doesn't attempt to enumerate the records until you call `return response.ToList<MyObject>();` at which time the `StreamReader` is already disposed.

```cs
    public class ImportManager
    {        
        [Ignore]
        public string FileSeperator { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public string Filename { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<T> ParseFile<T>() where T : class
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Filename))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = this.FileSeperator;
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                var results = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
                return results;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - that didn't make any difference.